# Ways to store Client ID and Secret securely for automated executions in Google Scripts

Tags: api, security, google-apps-script

I'm writing a Google Script that will call an external API and pull the resulting data into a Google Sheet. The API requires a Client ID and Secret value for authorization, and I need to keep those values secure. I would also like to trigger the script to run periodically (basically, I'm trying to automate the updating of this sheet as much as possible).

I'm no data security expert, but keeping the Client ID and Secret hardcoded seems like a terrible idea. Most of the search results I've found recommend using the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) to store those values, but in order to *set* those properties I'd have to hardcode them in the same script, correct? If so, that doesn't solve the security problem.

Other recommendations involve prompting the user to enter the credentials to authorize each run of the script. This solves the security requirement, but I want this process to be as automatic as possible. If I'm opening the script and providing my credentials each time it runs, then I may as well skip the triggered executions.

Are there any other solutions? For context, I am the only person who needs to access this script and no one else should be able to access the Client ID and Secret.

Comment: Maybe do it as a webapp with execute as you and only you can access it. Give users read only access to the spreadsheet

Comment: I've never used a webapp before. Can you point me toward any resources on how I'd use one for this?

Comment: Do other users need access to this script, or just you? If it's just you, I don't see any problem with hard-coding the client ID and secret. If other users have access to the script, and the script has access to this data, the other users will also have access to this data, no matter what. For example, even if this data is coming programmatically from an external source, users executing this can always [log](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) the data after this is imported (the same goes for `PropertiesService`).

Comment: Only I need to be able to edit, access, and run the script. Other people just need to view the spreadsheet with the data after the script has accessed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are the only one who has access to the script (having `View` access to the spreadsheet doesn't allow users to look at the bound script), hardcoding the `Client ID` and `Secret` shouldn't be a problem. Just don't give them `Edit` access to the spreadsheet.

If you don't want to hard-code the data directly anyway, you have some alternatives:

#### Using Properties Service:

Use [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties), as you mentioned. You could, for example, set the `Client ID` by running this once (in the legacy IDE, you can set these properties manually too):

```
function setClientId() {
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  props.setProperty('Client ID', '{YOUR_CLIENT_ID}');
}
```

Once the property was set, you can remove '{YOUR_CLIENT_ID}', or even the whole function, if you don't want to keep it hard-coded. The script could then retrieve the stored property the following way:

```
function getClientId() {
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  return props.getProperty('Client ID');
}
```

#### Using library:

Another option could be to store this information in a different script, to be used as a [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) (see [Gain access to a library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#gain_access_to_a_library)):

```
var CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
var SECRET = "YOUR_SECRET";
```

And then import this library in your main script (see [Add a library to your script project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#add_a_library_to_your_script_project)). In the sample below `LIBRARY` is the library `Identifier` name:

> Code.gs (from main script):

```
function getData() {
  const clientId = LIBRARY.CLIENT_ID;
  const secret = LIBRARY.SECRET;
  // ...
}
```

#### Note:

Please note that, even if you don't hard-code your data directly, anyone who can execute your script can potentially retrieve this data. For example, they could log what's returned by `getClientId()`.

If the script has access to some data, users who can execute the script can access this data too.