# How to securely use credentials in Google Apps Scripts (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, credentials, google-apps

What is the convention for having sensitive credentials in a Google Apps Script? For example if you are collecting information from external APIs.

My initial reading suggests [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) are the correct classes, but why do that rather than just hard coding it directly in the rest of the code... either way it seems to me that you're left with sensitive information hardcoded in Google Sheets Apps Scripts. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ways to store Client ID and Secret securely for automated executions in Google Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66700485/ways-to-store-client-id-and-secret-securely-for-automated-executions-in-google-s)

Comment: I think it does actually, thank you!